# Variable de visual no valido para la propiedad max-width de un estilo. En MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, vb.net, css3, razor

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<% For Each img In Model.listadoNoticias.Item(0).FOTO
       Dim id_LaImagen = "foto_" & img.IdFoto.ToString()
       Dim src_imagen = img.RutaFoto.Split("/")
       Dim ruta_Foto = Server.MapPath("~") & src_imagen(2) & "\" & src_imagen(3) & "\" _
       & src_imagen(4) & "\" & src_imagen(5) & "\" & src_imagen(6) & "\" & src_imagen(7)
       Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(ruta_Foto.ToString(), System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
       Dim LaImagen As System.Drawing.Image
       LaImagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
       Dim width_original = LaImagen.Width
       Dim height_original = LaImagen.Height
       Dim proporcion = width_original / height_original
       Dim max_width = 380 * proporcion & "px"
  %>
<li>                                                                                           
    <img alt="" id="foto_<%:img.IdFoto.ToString()%>"  
    src="<%:Html.Action("FotoNoticiaString", "Noticias", New With {.id = img.IdFoto}).ToString()%>" 
    style="max-height:380px;max-width:<%:max_width%>" class="img-responsive centrado_carrusel"/>                                           
</li>
```

El cual muestro imágenes en un Carousel Slider, en el obtengo las dimensiones originales para calcular su proporción, definiendo un alto fijo, y con la proporción obtener el ancho o ancho máximo.

El valor del ancho (`Dim max_width`) lo almaceno, para asignarlo al estilo de la imagen, en este caso al `max-width`, pero me dice que el valor no es válido.

Me gustaría saber cuál sería la manera correcta de asignarle el valor del Visual a una propiedad del estilo de la imagen. Cuando es una propiedad que no es del estilo, por ejemplo asignarle un id, clase, etc. de visual, no me indica la advertencia, pero en este caso sí.

Aquí muestro una imagen de lo que pasa
[image: el al max_width que está subrayado con verde me refiero]

Comment: Esa no es la sintaxis de Razor, los bloques de código deberían empezar con `@` no con `<%` esa es la sintaxis de web forms.  ¿Cual es la extensión de tu archivo de vista, es `.vbhtml`?

Comment: que version de asp.net mvc estas utilizando ?  estas seguro que el codigo que pusiste implementa razor ? porque codificas la logica en la view en lugar de hacerlo en el action del conteoller ?

Comment: Disculpen, no es razor, pero su comportamiento es similar, en vez de trabajar con el @, en este caso se trabaja con <%.
La extensión no es .vbhtml, sino que aspx. Estoy trabajando con MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es solo un aviso ya que por recomendación de la W3C, la propiedad [`max-width:`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) únicamente puede contener valores de:

```
none|longitud|porcentaje|initial|inherit
```

ejemplos:

```
max-width:none;
max-width:150px;  medida maxima en px, cm, etc.
max-width:150%; medida maxima en porcentaje
max-width:initial;
max-width:inherit
```

#### Esto no es ningún problema para impedir desplegar tu página correctamente!

Asegura que tu variable `proporcion` contenga un valor correcto.

```
<%
...
...
...
  Dim proporcion = 2
  Dim max_width = 380 * proporcion & "px"
 %>

style="max-height:380px;max-width:<%:max_width%>" class="img-responsive centrado_carrusel"/>
```

Comment: tienes razon, no tengo problemas para que funcione correctamente, pero me temía que en algun navegador o versión de ellos no funcione posteriormente, ya que me indicaba la advertencia con verde subrayado.

Comment: te puedo comentar desde hace 4 años tenemos un proyecto el cual funciona sin problema en navegadores Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera y Chrome, siempre tratamos de actualizar las últimas versiones. =)